# Insufficient active worker nodes. Waited 5.00m for at least 1 workers, but only 0 workers are active

Tags: docker, trino

I try to make trino cluster with 2 nodes (1 coordinator, 1 worker)
I am using docker trinodb/trino image
and changed its etc/[files] with the following config.properties.
coordinator config:

```
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=false
http-server.http.port=8080
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://localhost:8080
query.max-memory=30GB
query.max-memory-per-node=5GB
query.max-total-memory-per-node=10GB
http-server.authentication.type=PASSWORD
http-server.https.enabled=true
http-server.https.port=8443
http-server.https.keystore.path=/etc/trino/server.pem
```

worker config

```
coordinator=false
http-server.http.port=8083
discovery.uri=http://coordinatorIP:8083
query.max-memory=30GB
query.max-memory-per-node=5GB
query.max-total-memory-per-node=10GB
```

but I got the following error:

```
Query 20210309_074153_00003_ry76t failed: Insufficient active worker nodes. Waited 5.00m for at least 1 workers, but only 0 workers are active
```

My docker compose file is :

```
version: '3'
services:
  presto:
    restart: always
    image: trinodb/trino
    container_name: trino
    volumes:
      - ./etc:/etc/trino
      - ./plugin:/usr/lib/trino/plugin
      - ./etc:/usr/usr/lib/trino/etc
    ports:
      - 9581:8443
      - 8083:8080
```

Note : It seems connected and does not throw any errors and if I stop the master it throws :

```
trino     | 2021-03-09T08:04:13.200Z    ERROR   Announcer-3 io.airlift.discovery.client.Announcer   Service announcement failed after 1.80ms. Next request will happen within 1.00ms
```

But as I mentioned it does not execute any query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was node.properties and its node.id. Each server needs a unique node.id

Comment: How did you add it in the yaml can you show me?

Comment: it was not in yaml 
there is another file which name is node.properties which has specification for a node and avalibale on each node. change the node.id there

Comment: We are doing a helm and node.properties is a single configuration for all worker nodes.

Comment: @yasinmohammed I really do not know about that, but pretty sure you can not have single node.properties for all the worker nodes